# Is the problem here the reference created using a rvalue instead of a lvalue?

Tags: c++, vector, lvalue

I would like to understand the problem with the following code. It does compile but it doesn´t work as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
  public:
    std::vector<int> getVector() { return m_vector; }
    std::vector<int> m_vector = {1, 2, 3};
};

int main()
{
    A objA;

    for(int i = 0; i < objA.getVector().size(); i++)
    {
         int &item = objA.getVector().at(i);
         std::cout << "\nvector item: " << item;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

- vector item: 0
- vector item: 0
- vector item: 3

Expected output:

- vector item: 1
- vector item: 2
- vector item: 3

I understand that there is no need to declare the item as a reference but I would like to understand the problem that arises after doing it this way.

I think that the problem is that the reference item expects a lvalue and method **std::vector::at** returns a reference. As the return type of method **std::vector::at** is **int&**, the compilation doesn´t throw any error but then the result is not as expected.

Would it be possible to confirm if this is the problem and I´m not missing anything else?

Comment: Yes, you're missing the factor that the vector who's `at()` you just called, immediately vanishes into a black hole, never to be seen again, leaving you with a reference to a destroyed object. It's not the reference itself, that's a problem, it's that it's a reference to an object that gets immediately destroyed. You're not, by chance, coming from Java background and trying to learn C++?

Answer (score 3):

`getVector()` returns a `std::vector` by-value. Therefore `objA.getVector().at(i)` is calling `.at(i)` on a temporary object.

`.at` returns a reference to the element at the given position. `int &item` is bound to this referenced element *of the temporary object*.

After the line

```
int &item = objA.getVector().at(i);
```

the temporary `std::vector` is destroyed and with it the element that `item` is referencing.

So using that reference then in

```
std::cout << "\nvector item: " << item;
```

causes undefined behavior, because the object that `item` was referencing doesn't exist anymore.

This can be fixed by returning by-reference from `getVector`, in which case `item` will refer to the element in the `std::vector` member of `objA` and not a temporary copy of it.